# "loop" wiring screw terminals of multiple outlets in branch circuit

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

When wiring multiple outlets of a branch typically a long length of cable is roughed in. Installing the outlets usually results in a lot of excess wire cut off and 2 wrapped screws for each hot and neutral to continue this parallel supply down the line. I see great benefit to what I read is allowed in Canada where just enough lead it brought to the box at rough in. To connect the outlet, a loop of the conductor is (1) skinned or (2) slit and wrapped around the (one) screw.

The benefits are: no discarded copper cutoffs, quicker only 1 screw terminal needed, no ambiguity about wrapping the wire the wrong way around the screw, increased reliability - each screw terminal, wire nut connection junction etc. provides a resistance point/failure opportunity - more so than a continuous unbroken wire.

I think there was some argument that skinning the insulation might reduce the copper thickness. I think you really have to be careless for that to occur and besides, that part of the wire is bolstered under the conductive screw head. Slitting would solve that concern as no copper would then be removed.

What do you think? Can we overcome the concerns to utilize that method here? What is needed to change the code?

Comment: Why would skinning the wire damage the conductor more than stripping a free end? You use the same tool.

Comment: Welcome. Be aware that we're not a discussion forum. Your question is rather broad and somewhat subjective. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

> I see great benefit to what I read is allowed in Canada where **just enough lead is brought to the box** at rough in.

That's not allowed in Canada, you still need the full conductor length.  So you don't save the foot of wire you think you do.

If you were seeing installations with a scanty length of wire in the box of < 6" or 150mm each side of the screw, you were viewing a fool's work. That was a code violation due to too short length.

> To connect the outlet, a loop of the conductor is (1) skinned or (2) slit and wrapped around the (one) screw.

That's totally allowed in the USA.

> The benefits are: no discarded copper cutoffs, quicker only 1 screw terminal needed

Cross off speed. If speed was a motivating factor, you would cut the wires and use backstabs.

> I think there was some argument that skinning the insulation might reduce the copper thickness.

That's not an issue for anyone competent. If you nick a wire, then just cut and do it the old fashioned way.    (Using the spare length anyone but a fool would leave themselves).

There are better ways to save money on wire.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Harper's answer:

- If you do things reasonably well, the excess is not all that much. If you end up with an extra 6" - 12" (beyond what needs to be left in the box), you can save those pieces of Romex and use the wires for pigtails.
- If you are really after *quality*, you go for the better grade receptacles that have screw-to-clamp, so you just have to strip the wires but not bend them, and the connection is super-easy but without the problems of backstabs. Of course, if an extra $0.50 per receptacle of wasted wire bothers you then an extra $1.00 per receptacle for better quality will *really* bother you.

**Cheap, fast, good - pick 2 out of 3.**

- Cheap + fast = backstabs
- Cheap + good = learn proper techniques
- Fast + good = better quality receptacles

For builders, it often ends up cheap + fast. I understand that.

For a homeowner just doing a little here, a little there, go for the good stuff. Just not calling an electrician one time to install or replace a receptacle will save more than you'll ever spend on extra wire and better quality receptacles and switches.